# Galleriffic not working in IE7 or IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, image-gallery

I'm trying to use Galleriffic. My images are not coming through in IE7 or IE8 — there is just white space where the images should be. It is working fine for me in other browsers.

Has anyone had any problems implementing Galleriffic with IE? More specifically, how can I get my images to appear?

Answer (score 1):

You will never get any version of IE to attempt to perform like other far more modern browsers  without a proper doctype. Add this to the first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score -1):

Yah, doesn't work in IE.  Their sample page does not work or even render correctly.

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-1.html